# Send images using parse and sinch

Tags: android, parse-platform, sinch

I  am working on an android Instant messaging application using parse and sinch so far I am able to send text messages between users (one on one). I would like to know if theres a way that I can send media files like images,videos, etc. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can not have attachments on an IM message with sinch.